# Getting this simple problem while importing Xgboost on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, xgboost

Everything was running fine in Jupyter notebook until I imported Xgboost. As soon as I import it I get the problem below. I have Python 3.8 and have installed it via terminal pip3 method, what should I do next?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a81e4513ce38> in <module>
      1 # Let's Learn about the stock market using XGBOOST
      2 
----> 3 import xgboost as xgb

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/__init__.py in <module>
      9 import warnings
     10 
---> 11 from .core import DMatrix, DeviceQuantileDMatrix, Booster
     12 from .training import train, cv
     13 from . import rabit  # noqa

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in <module>
    173 
    174 # load the XGBoost library globally
--> 175 _LIB = _load_lib()
    176 
    177 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in _load_lib()
    156     if not lib_success:
    157         libname = os.path.basename(lib_paths[0])
--> 158         raise XGBoostError(
    159             'XGBoost Library ({}) could not be loaded.\n'.format(libname) +
    160             'Likely causes:\n' +

XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (libxgboost.dylib) could not be loaded.
Likely causes:
  * OpenMP runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, 
       libomp.dylib for Mac OSX, libgomp.so for Linux and other UNIX-like OSes). 
       Mac OSX users: Run `brew install libomp` to install OpenMP runtime.
  * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS
Error message(s): ['dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.dylib\n  Reason: image not found']
```

Comment: Solved I installed libomp.dylib for Mac OSX

Comment: Any idea how to do this on linux?

Answer (score 38):

I solved it by installing libomp.dylib for Mac OSX. The answer was there all along.

You can do it by running the following command :

`brew install libomp`

Comment: This fixed it for me too.

Comment: agreed, and to be specific i did `brew install libomp`

Comment: This didn't work for me on a M1 mac

Answer (score 18):

for Mac OSX, just run 'brew install libomp'
[image]

Comment: The error message said that `is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))`. I think that it is still an unsolved issue for m1 mac users. btw, I had put the libomp.dylib to : `/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib`

Answer (score 12):

If you use anaconda, you can use:

```
conda install py-xgboost
```

Comment: This worked for me on M1 Mac! No success even after `brew install libomp`

Comment: Thanks for sharing! That solved it for me as well!

Answer (score 9):

The cause is that xgboost is looking for the dynamic library at the following locations, which is not where it might be installed to.

```
Reason: tried: '/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/michaeltu/third-party/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file)"]
```

First, `brew install libomp` if you haven't done so.

After that, check where brew installed the library.

```
$ brew info libomp
libomp: stable 12.0.0 (bottled)
LLVM's OpenMP runtime library
https://openmp.llvm.org/
/opt/brew/Cellar/libomp/12.0.0 (9 files, 1.5MB) *
```

We see it installed it here:

```
$ ls /opt/brew/Cellar/libomp/12.0.0/lib/
libomp.a    libomp.dylib
```

Make a simlink (based on the version of libomp you installed):

```
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/libomp/
$ ln -s /opt/brew/Cellar/libomp/12.0.0/lib /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib
```

Try importing it again. This was able to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 4):

You must install brew on your MAC first: https://brew.sh/ (Brew might take a moment to install)
Then run the following in your terminal: `brew install libomp`

Answer (score 3):

If `brew install libomp` doesn't work, `libomp` might be installed to a different place.

xgboost needs `libomp.dylib` under `usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib`, but `brew` may install it under `/opt/brew/Cellar/libomp/11.0.1/lib/libomp.dylib`. You can copy yours to the xgboost required path.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it as below if you have Python 3.7 or higher:

```
!brew install libomp
```

Answer (score 1):

Below command worked for me if you are using anaconda

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```